# how to check the contents of a viewbag in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag

Is there any way to check viewbag content, what the viewbag has of data in the view.
my controller send possibly new data each time i click on button and send it with the same named viewbag.

here my controller

```
public ActionResult Details(string IncomRequest, Int Id)
  {
// some code......
    switch (IncomRequest)
    {

        case ("Order"):
            ViewBag.Query = list<Ordr> Ord;
           break;

        case ("Process"):
            ViewBag.Query = lis<Process> pro;
            break;
   }
  return view();
```

in my view i want to check what the viewbag contains 
is it  Ord or pro.

Comment: Why not just create 2 different ViewBag, one for pro and one for Ord and check both to see which one is empty?

Comment: Have you considered using strongly-typed views?

Comment: I would create two separate actions, possibly even controllers, why pass in `IncomRequest`, i.e. `OrderDetails(int id)` and `ProcessDetails(int id)` Single Responsibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view you can do something like this:

```
// if this is true then there's nothing there
@if (ViewBag.Query == null)
```

further you can do this:

```
// it was set by the "Order" case
@if (ViewBag.Query is List<Ordr>)
```

Comment: Im not using strongly-typed view,  And my view is not binded to any modell. so the view dosent know what List<Order> is

Comment: @FadiAlkadi, that doesn't have anything to do with the view being, or not being, strongly typed. You just need to provide the full namespace declarations in the view (i.e. my code) or provide them as includes in the `web.config`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can

```
@if(ViewBag.Query is List<Ordr>)
{
    // List<Ordr>
}
else if(ViewBag.Query is List<Process>)
{
    // List<Process>
}
```